# MySQL Master/Slave - Auto Server Id

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, master-slave

I currently have a single dedicated machine hosting my MySQL instance and I'm looking at moving to a Master/Slave replication setup. I've configured a test master and slave as per the usual tutorials and it works fine.
However, my application runs on AWS using a Load Balancer and Auto-Scaling etc...
So new instances are added and removed. Each of these will have a local MySQL instance for reads. Can I configure the "server-id" in my.cnf to auto-assign? If not how would I do this with a dynamically sizing set of slave nodes?

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic sizing of _databases_ sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.  The Master node has to grow, too.  So it can't be easily automated.

Comment: What would be the best approach then to scale out a MySQL backed application that runs on a Load-Balanced stack? For example, say its a RESTful web service with lots of CRUD operations? I'm not married to the idea of Master/Slave - I just assumed it would fit the mould.

Comment: Oh, which "scale out" are you referring to?  More data?  Or More activity?

Comment: Hhhmmm, Activity I would imagine primarily. So say I have a RESTful web service with a lot of activity. Each request in some way interacts with the DB, but the majority of requests involve reads. As traffic increases new nodes get added to handle the traffic. But the database remains a possible bottleneck as at present it is a single machine accepting connections from multiple nodes in its network. So my thinking was to have the single master for writes and each node would have its own local (synced) slave for reads.

Comment: Let's see the slowest queries -- perhaps we can speed them up, thereby not needing more and more Slaves.

Comment: Ah... This is more of a future proofing exercise! :) 
This is an in-development project and I just feel that the MySQL aspect could be improved upon. Maybe I'm coming at this from the wring angle...

Comment: CRUD must go to the Master, so multiple slaves won't help in Scaling.  `SELECTs` can be scaled via Slaves.  I would suggest than only 2% of systems need more horsepower than can be delivered by a single server _after_ optimizing the indexes, schema, selects, etc.

Comment: (And I am avoiding your AWS questions, since I know nothing about that.)

Comment: Offtopic. This is more DB configuration, and not programming. This should be on the DBA site.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the idea of having local MySQL instances on the Load Balancer nodes such a bad idea? Does it not provide an inherent performance increase by keeping reads local? What if for example some of the slave nodes are in different geographic regions to the Master node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using Auto Scaling, then you should move your database off the Auto Scaled instances. Each Auto Scaled instance should not have it's own copy of the database.

Instead:

1. Have a master database that is not part of an Auto Scaling group.
2. Have 0 or more read-replicas to help alleviate load on your database while reading
3. Have the EC2 instances that are part of your Auto Scaling group reference your not-auto-scaled database nodes as needed.

This way, as EC2 instances scale up/down/in/out, your database stays put separated from those instances.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was going for a sort of halfway-house. A single dedicated master instance (not in an auto-scale group) and then each auto-scaled node would have a local slave copy for quicker reads. But this doesn't seem to be the way to go. If I had 0 or more read-replicas how would I distribute the load? Thanks!

Comment: Just round robin the read connections. Actually, some of the MySql connectors have automatic read replica balancing (done client side).

Comment: I ended up going with Amazon RDS and using its Read-Replica features as suggested in this response

Comment: One question though, how can get the end-points of the replicas in the auto-scaling-group and have them added automatically in my application-code?